# Case when with replace in sql server

Tags: sql-server, replace, case-when

I have created a select statement

```
SELECT [source_name]+''''/''''+[schema_name]+''''/''''+[table_name] AS [path], 
       [application_name], 
       [database_name], 
       [schema_name], 
       [table_name], 
       [source_name], 
       Substring(source_table_name, 0, 3)           AS source, 
       replace([query],''''desc'''',''''"DESC"'''') AS query, 
FROM   [cdi].[parameter_master] p (nolock) 
JOIN   [cdi].application_master a (nolock) 
ON     a.application_id = p.application_id
```

In this part
`replace([query],''''desc'''',''''\"DESC\"'''') as query`

[query] value is

```
SELECT a.desc, 
       a.occ_desc            AS occ_desc, 
       a.dth_dt              AS dth_dt, 
       a.hire_dt             AS hire_dt, 
       a.insd_empe_nbr       AS insd_empe_nbr, 
       a.surg_ind            AS surg_ind, 
       a.src_clm_pty_id      AS src_clm_pty_id, 
       a.elmtry_clm_anchr_id AS elmtry_clm_anchr_id, 
       a.lic_nbr_txt         AS lic_nbr_txt, 
       a.atty_hire_rsn_desc  AS atty_hire_rsn_desc, 
       a.atty_catg_desc      AS atty_catg_desc, 
       a.dfns_appt_dt        AS dfns_appt_dt, 
       a.empr_nm             AS empr_nm, 
       a.extl_refr_cd        AS extl_refr_cd, 
       a.src_sys_cd          AS src_sys_cd 
FROM   dbaall.pty_rol_in_clm a 
WHERE  a.e_tistmp >= timestamp('2018-01-01     00:00:00') 
OR     ( 
              a.e_to_tistmp >= timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00') 
       AND    a.e_to_tistmp < timestamp('2018-03-31 00:00:00'))
```

I want to only replace `a.DESC` to `a.\"DESC\"`

But the `replace()` function replaces all DESC occurrence in [query] string.

I want to write a case when statement based on if .desc found then only replace else string should not get replaced.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe simple :
`replace([query],''''a.DESC'''',''''a.\"DESC\"'''')` ?

Comment: Or `replace([query],''''.DESC'''',''''.\"DESC\"'''')`

Comment: Slighty off topic but you should read this before you continue splattering NOLOCK everywhere. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: thank you @killer Queen,@JNevil for answers. I resolved the issue by Killer Queen's approach.@Sean Lange- Thank you for sharing the blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code resolved the issue:
replace([query],''''a.DESC'''',''''a.\"DESC\"'''')